# $pq\mid pn^q+qn^p+kn$ for some $k,\,$ if $p,q$ are primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I get some troubles with this problem, could you help me?
Given prime numbers $p$ and $q$ prove $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $pn^q+qn^p+kn$ is a multiple of $pq,~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What about using the CRT?

Comment: CRT not really needed. Just Fermat's little Theorem. But note, the problem needs $p,q$ to be _distinct_ primes (else the problem is wrong). First consider the expression mod $p$, then mod $q$. A valid $k$ will then be obvious.

Comment: Sorry -- my previous comment is wrong -- you do need CRT. Also, $p,q$ need not be distinct. But my other hints are still OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Write it as $\ p(n^{\large q}\!-n)+q(n^{\large p}\!-n) +\!\! \overbrace{(p\!+\!q+k)}^{\large =\ 0\ \ {\rm if}\ \ k\ =\ \ldots}\!\!\!n\ $ and apply little Fermat